# Allow + sign in email address AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a processing url which is AMPScript like below in which email_address is a paramater which is passed. This email_address has a `+` sign in it.

```
https://pages.email.xyz.com/processing-in/?email_address=xyz+abc@gmail.com
```

whenever i am doing a raiseerror to check this value, i am not getting the `+` sign in the email address. I am getting a blank space in between like `xyz abc@gmail.com`

How i can capture this entire email address and insert it in DE.

Regards

Comment: The error is due to the data type of email address in the data extension. An email address cannot have space and special characters. You should change the data type of the field knowing that as a consequence you couldn't use this field in order to send email to subscribers

Comment: We cant change the data type. Is there any workaround for this...

Comment: The only way is to remove the space (xyzabc@gmail.com). But do you confirm that this email is existing?

Comment: The business wants to xyz+abc@gmail.com this mail should get passed...i am not sure how to do it..

Comment: When you use to RequestParameter()/QueryParameters() to pull that email from url to page that function replaces the "+" sign in it with space. I haven't done any testing on that and I'm not sure if only this sign is replaced with space - if yes you can just replace all spaces back with "+" sign. Alternatively you can encrypt/encode that parameter and then decrypt/decode it after getting it from url - should work as well .

Comment: I  can confirm the emailaddress data type does support email address that include + symbols. MBB's explaination is right on, this issue stems from the RequestParameter()/QueryParameters() functions.  You can add the + back into the email address by using the ampscript Replace() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on @MBB's comment:

```
%%[

var @email

set @email = iif(empty(RequestParameter("email_address")),QueryParameter("email_address"),"")

set @email = replace(@email," ","+")

]%%

Email: %%=v(@email)=%%
```

Reference:

- [**requestParameter()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/requestparameter/)
- [**queryParamter()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/queryparameter/)
- [**empty()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/empty/)
- [**iif()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/iif/)